# Excel Powerquery- is it possible to "replace" a table source (relationships, pivot tables)?

Tags: database, excel, powerquery

I used Powerquery to connect to an Access DB and loaded several related tables. One of them contains information on customers. I've created tables and charts based on these tables.

Now I want to "replace" the customer table in Access with a customer table in Oracle without reestablishing the relationships such that all the pivot tables and charts will refresh without necessitating recreation.

The tables have the same headers and hold the same data. But the number of records differ. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Source step of your query to point to the Oracle database instead of Access. The first line of your query should currently be something like

```
Access.Database("database location")
```

In theory you can just change it to

```
Oracle.Database("database location", "other options")
```

You can find some basic documentation on the Oracle connector in Power Query on the MSDN/Microsoft site.